# Отправка e-mail через mailto://

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

Доброго времени суток. Мне нужна помощь в решении такой проблемы: в проекте есть Text Field, в котором пользователь вводит адрес e-mail. Далее при нажатии на кнопку выполняется переход по URL-схеме mailto. Сейчас мой код имеет такой вид:

```
- (IBAction)sendMailButton:(id)sender
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"mailto:example@example.com?&subject=Example&body=Hello%20World!"]];
}
```

Нужно сделать так, чтобы вместо "example@example.com" вставлялось значение Text Field. Как это сделать? Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вроде так:

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"mailto:%@?&subject=Example&body=Hello%20World!", self.textField.text]]];
```

Только я бы добавил проверку на такой URL.

Comment: Спасибо огромное, все работает. Проверку обязательно добавлю